# Why is my program causing IDLE to crash?

Tags: python, crash, append, permutation, python-idle

I am trying to create a program that takes a scrambled word from the user and then compares it to a list and looks for similar words and then shows the user possible word matches.

However, whenever I run the program it crashes the IDLE. So my question is why is it crashing IDLE?

```
def anagrams(s):
    if s =="":
        return [s]
    else:
        ans = []
        for u in anagrams(s[1:]):
            for pos in range(len(u)+1):
                ans.append(u[:pos]+s[0]+u[pos:])
            return ans


def unscramble(x):
    clean_unscram = []
    word1 = open(x, 'r')
    word2 = word1.read()
    word3 = word2.lower()
    word4 = word3.split()
    scrambled = anagrams(input('Pease enter a jumbled word:'))
    #everything below this line is for sorting the words and then adding it to the clean_unscram(bled) list
    for anagram in scrambled:
        if anagram in word4:
            for anagram in word4:
                if anagram not in clean_unscram:
                    clean_unscram.append(word4)
                    break
                    return clean_unscram
```

Comment: Can you provide error ouput?

Comment: Does your code appear exactly as in the post? It doesn't look like valid python indentation...

Comment: The current code runs fine (defines two functions) in both 2.7 and 3.4.  Since there is no crash, I suggest closing this.